# extract security value using regex

Tags: regex

I need the value 2ebd09a37a extraxted using regex. There are three occurrences of "security"

var competitions_ajax_object = {"ajax_url":"https://gg.se/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php","security":"2ebd09a37a"};

Comment: What have you tried? `"security"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"` but better to use native functions.

Comment: You have a Javascript object, why not simply use `competitions_ajax_object.security` or `competitions_ajax_object['security']`? and what do you mean by "There are three occurrences"?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various regex`.

I need the value 2ebd09a37a so that i can use that as a variable in the next request in jmeter.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
     /* <![CDATA[ */
      var brp_ajax_object = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/33.se\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","security":"e77fe04e78"};
     /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     /* <![CDATA[ */
      var competitions_ajax_object = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/33.se\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","security":"2fbd19a36a"};
   
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     /* <![CDATA[ */
      var ajax_object = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/33.se\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","security":"e7f58g2d85"};
     /* ]]> */</script>